# What's the magic behind the block in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
{
  function foo() { console.info('999'); }
  foo = 2
}

console.info(foo)
```

Vert interesting! It outputs a function instead of number, why is that ?

Comment: `foo = 2` assigns to the binding *internal to the block*, whereas the function gets put on the `window`

Comment: @CertainPerformance foo without let/const/var should also has the same effect (attach to window.)

Comment: The difference is that `function foo` creates a binding inside in addition to outside. Without that, the `foo = 2` creates only one binding, on the window

Comment: I don't get it. If I change the order of two lines of code, the result is different, I don't know why it's related to `binding`, can you help provide some demos plz ?

Comment: Did you look at the canonical? That's what it's there for, it explains what's going on